# Check if listview items contains specified data then start next activity

Tags: android, listview, custom-adapter

I have a `Listview` of `custom adapter` which has five fields in it. 
`Name`, `Cnic`, `No`, `Desgination` and `attendance`. Now what i want to do is that i have to check whether all the list items have some value written after `attendance column`. If there is any thing on `attendance column` then the user can move to next `activity` otherwise it will prompt user to mark attendance.

Here is my code for getting value and setting in the `adapter`.

```
  for (int p = 0; p < teacherList.size(); p++) {
        details = new DetailsTeacherwebservice();
        //ArrayList<Object> baris = data.get(p);
        details.setId(teacherList.get(p).getId());
        details.setTeachername(teacherList.get(p).getTeachername());
        details.setTeachercnic(teacherList.get(p).getTeachercnic());
        details.setTeacherno(teacherList.get(p).getTeacherno());
        details.setTeachergender(teacherList.get(p).getTeachergender());
        details.setAttendance(teacherList.get(p).getAttendance());

        addas.add(details);
    }
    cusadapter = new CustomAdapterTeacherWebservice(TeacherWebserviceMainList.this, addas);
    listcontent.setAdapter(cusadapter);
```

Here is the code for moving to next `activity`

```
next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent view_order_intent = new Intent(TeacherList.this, M_TeacherPresenceList.class);
            startActivity(view_order_intent);
            finish();
        }
    });
```

User can not move to next `activity` if `attendance` is `empty` or `Null` so that user has to mark attendance for all teachers in the list and then can go to next.
Please Help

Comment: you want to check attendance for that particular record or all the records?

Comment: @PareshMayani for all records in the list. i.e. if there are 10 items then all the 10 items attendance should be marked otherwise prompt the user to mark attendance for all

Comment: @PareshMayani can you please help me out?

Comment: @ArslanAli Try to write foreach to check all attendance item are marked if it is yes then move to next activity else show prompt

Comment: @R2R Can you please provide a sample code for it?

Comment: next.setonclick is it button or list click position

Comment: this is button, it just checks if attendancec is marked for all items, if yes then user can move to next activity otherwise not

Comment: teacherList.get(p).getAttendance() this is string or boolean

Comment: teacherList is arraylist of the teacherclass model

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162272/discussion-between-r2r-and-arslan-ali).

Comment: @ArslanAli   try my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this**

```
    ArrayList<Boolean> isAllMarked = new ArrayList<>();
    int attentednceMarkedCount = 0;
    for (int p = 0; p < teacherList.size(); p++) {
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(teacherList.get(p).getAttendance())) {
            isAllMarked.add(true);
        } else {
            isAllMarked.add(false);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < isAllMarked.size(); i++) {
        if (isAllMarked.get(i)) {  //if marked true
            attentednceMarkedCount = attentednceMarkedCount + 1;
        }
    }

    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (attentednceMarkedCount ==teacherList.size()) {
                Intent view_order_intent = new Intent(TeacherList.this, M_TeacherPresenceList.class);
                startActivity(view_order_intent);
                finish();
            } else {
                showAlert()
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Ok let me test :)

Answer (score 1):

write a method returning boolean value to check if any one of the attendance is missing, when the missing attendance is found, the loop is exited immediately so that attendanceStatus is accurate.

```
private boolean hasAllAttendance(){
    boolean attendanceStatus= true;

 for (int p = 0; p < teacherList.size(); p++) {
    details = new DetailsTeacherwebservice();

    if(teacherList.get(p).getAttendance() == null || 
           teacherList.get(p).getAttendance().equal("") ){
        attendanceStatus = false;
        break;
    }
  return attendanceStatus;
}
```

now, using this method, control your activity transition or toast message

```
next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    if(hasAllAttendance()){           
        Intent view_order_intent = new 
        Intent(TeacherList.this, M_TeacherPresenceList.class);
        startActivity(view_order_intent);
        finish();
    } else //Toast message

  }
});
```

Comment: Ok let me test please

Comment: welcome. try to use 'for each' loops for iterating objects as accessing objects in a list using index is error prone.
and please accept the answer if it's the correct one for you.

Answer (score 0):

//Try this

```
boolean attendance = false;

    for (int p = 0; p < teacherList.size(); p++) {
        details = new DetailsTeacherwebservice();

        if (teacherList.get(p).getAttendance() != null ||
                teacherList.get(p).getAttendance().equal("")) {
            attendance = true;
        } else {
            attendance = false;
        }
    }

    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (attendance) {
                Intent view_order_intent = new
                        Intent(TeacherList.this, M_TeacherPresenceList.class);
                startActivity(view_order_intent);
                finish();
            } else {//Toast mark attendance}

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Ok let me test this :)

Answer (score 0):

Use your `next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()` on `getView()` method of `Adapter`. Like -

```
private boolean checkAttendance(){
    boolean hasAll = true;

 for (int i = 0; i < teacherList.size(); i++) {
    if(att.empty() || att == null){
        hasAll = false;
        break;
    }
  return hasAll ;
}
```

on `getView()` method -

```
next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          if(checkAttendance()){
            Intent view_order_intent = new Intent(TeacherList.this, M_TeacherPresenceList.class);
            startActivity(view_order_intent);
            finish();
           }else{
             showYourCustomAlert()  // your alert dialog
           }
        }
    });
```

Comment: And what `teacherList.get(p).getAttendance()` returns ? is it boolean? or String?

Comment: it returns string